# userId doesn't get saved

Tags: meteor

I have a `visitInsert` function in `lib/collections/visits.js` to save a visit.
It also adds the userId of the logged in user, but currently the visit gets saved alright, but when I look in the mongo database, it hasn't saved the `userId`. This is the `visitInsert` function:

```
Meteor.methods({
  visitInsert: function(visitAttributes) {
    check(Meteor.userId(), String);
    check(visitAttributes, {
      visit_date: String,
      name: String
    });

    var properties = {
      userId: this.userId
    };

    var visit = _.extend(visitAttributes, properties);
    var visitId = Visits.insert(visit);
    return {
      _id: visitId
    };
  }
});
```

So what is wrong here?

Updated:

In `lib/collections/visits.js` I have added some console.log to see what the values are:

```
console.log(visit);
console.log(visit.userId);
var visitId = Visits.insert(visit);
```

Both `visit` and `visit.userId` are filled with correct values, so with the ID of the current logged in user. But when save to the database with `Visits.insert`, the visit gets saved, but without `userId`???

Updated 2:

Added the `allow` callback in `visits.js`:

```
Visits.allow({
  insert: function (userId, visit) { return !! userId; },
  update: function(userId, visit) { return ownsDocument(userId, visit); },
  remove: function(userId, visit) { return ownsDocument(userId, visit); }
});
```

Solution: the issue had nothing to do with an `allow` callback, because it was called from a method. I discovered that because I am using the `aldeed:collection2` package, I need to explicitly check all attributes. Not only the ones coming from a form, but also the ones I add in the insert method.

Comment: insert returns undefined actually. as far as i know.

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-insert   first line :)

Comment: is `this.userId` something?   why not `var properties = { userId: Meteor.userId()}`

Comment: Al right. Pretty sure I read somewhere recently that it returns undefined. Believe those docs are usually out of date.

Comment: docs are good, it returns an _id.  You can easily see the code for insert if you look at the code in your browser console.  If you have a meteor app, go  `Blah = new Mongo.Collection('blah)`  then type `Blah.insert`   should show you the code for insert ( well, in chrome it does)

Comment: when changed to ``var properties = { userId: Meteor.userId()}`` it still does not save the ``userId``, but I am logged in.

Comment: What happens if you add a `console.log(Meteor.userId());` and look at the server console? Your method is run on both client and server, but the important is what the server output as the server controls what's actually written to the DB (unless you have added allow rules to enable the client to write directly to the DB).

Comment: I have updated my question with some futher investigation results

Comment: I put your code into [meteorpad.com](http://meteorpad.com/pad/uQ9kS3F7Pr73uJHAE/insertUserID) where the problem you describe does not exist.  Perhaps some other code you have not shown causes the issue.

Comment: Interesting, the only thing what can cause a problem would be allow and deny, right? I have added them to the question

Comment: I added the allow rules and the code still works as expected with userId saved to db.  It is not clear what is causing your issue but if you are using allow / deny rules you can simply your code by just calling `Visits.insert` directly from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Like Keith Nicholas said use:

```
var properties = { 
   userId: Meteor.userId()
}
```

Your allow function seems weird. I would set something like this:

```
// check if user is owner of object
ownsObject = function (userId, obj) {
    return obj && obj.userId === userId;
};

Visits.allow({
  insert: ownsObject,
  update: ownsObject,
  remove: ownsObject
});
```

Also, it is not clear what you are using. Are you using the method "visitInsert" you defined? If so, you shouldn't need to define any allow, if you are calling Meteor.call('visitInsert', function(){}) on the client. Besides, if you are making a call you should pass Meteor.userId() as parameter to your method because Meteor.userId() doesn't exist server side.

To sum up, I would suggest you to build the "visitAttributes" client side WITH the Meteor.userId(). And just call your server side method that only check attributes and Visits.insert(visitAttributes).

BETTER: create an object "visit" that you want to insert and make your call:

client side:

```
var visit = {
  visit_date: getYourDate,
  name: getYourName,
  userId: Meteor.userId()
}

Meteor.call("visitInsert", visit, function(err, res){
  if(!err){
    Console.log("Visit inserted!");
  }
});
```

server side:

```
Meteor.methods({
  visitInsert: function(visit) {
    check(visit.userId, String);
    check(visit, {
      visit_date: String,
      name: String
    });

    return Visits.insert(visit);
  }
});
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tonight and come back to you

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
var properties = { 
   userId: Meteor.userId()
}
```

Comment: Nope, the visit is in the database, but without ``userId``, also when changed to ``userId: Meteor.userId()``.